# Get number of approved comments of post

Tags: wordpress

In my wordpress theme i use

```
<?php $commentscount = get_comments_number(); echo $commentscount; ?>
```

to show the number of comments of the specific post.

The problem is: It returns the total comment count (including deleted comments etc.)
I only want to show the number of **approved** comments. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `wp_count_comments($postid);`

```
<?php
$comments_count = wp_count_comments($postid);
echo "Comments approved: " . $comments_count->approved ;
?>
```

This returns an object containing all the needed data about comments.

So you can use it like,

```
echo "Comments in moderation: " . $comments_count->moderated; 
echo "Comments approved: " . $comments_count->approved;
echo "Comments in Spam: " . $comments_count->spam;
echo "Comments in Trash: " . $comments_count->trash;
echo "Total Comments: " . $comments_count->total_comments;
```

Comment: And inside the current post?
I tried:
`<?php $postid = get_post(); $commentscount = wp_count_comments(     $postid->ID ); echo $comments_count->approved; ?>`
But no results.

Comment: To get the id inside the loop use `$postid = get_the_ID();`

Comment: Its outside of loop

Comment: Can you echo `$postid` and and see whether `get_post()` actually returning a post object?

Comment: Current code is:
`<?php global $wp_query; $postid = $wp_query->post->ID; echo $postid; $commentscount = wp_count_comments( $postid ); echo $comments_count->approved; ?>`
I can echo the $postid. But it wont echo the $commentscount.

Comment: Ok.. its because of $commentscount =! $comments_count. Totally missed that typo. Sorry and thank you so much. It works fine now.
`<?php global $post; $commentscount = wp_count_comments( $post->ID ); echo $commentscount->approved; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Use below WP function:

```
$comment_array = get_approved_comments($post_id);
$approvedComments = count($comment_array);
```